# opencart 301 old url to new url redirection error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart2.x

Am using `Opencart Version 2.1.0.1`. Am trying to redirect `old url` to `new url`
 via `.htaccess` it's not working.

this is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !https://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=62_100/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/personalized/fridge-magnets/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?route=product/category&path=62_100[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /personalized/fridge-magnets? [R=301,L]
```